# How to read ubuntu file in web browser

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, nginx

I have a rather simple task, but the fact that I know little about Ubuntu and linux in general doesn't allow me to do it myself.

I have a .txt file on my Ubuntu DigitalOcean server that I need to access via web browser. Location: home/botuser/phantombot/addons/test.txt
Ubuntu has 2 users: root and botuser.
The server runs on it's own IP without domain.

So the question is how do I setup nginx, or maybe any other simple server so that I can access with file from url like 45.88.235.230/test.txt. Maybe there are easier solutions to this problem that I may not know of.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have nginx setup for anything? 
If not, start with a simple nginx guide, e.g. here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html

There you will end with something like that in your /etc/nginx config

```
server {
   listen 80;
   root /data/www;

   location / {
   }
}
```

Then copy your .txt file to /data/www

Comment: Michael thanks for the info. The problem is that I have to access the file directly. The file is updating every minute.

Comment: Thats fine with nginx, it will always allow you to access to current file. if you have it stored somewhere else you can use e.g. a cronjob:
crontab -e
* /1 * * * * mv /home/me/file.txt /data/www/file.txt